# git push local branch to server

Tags: git, git-push

I have a cloned repository to my local folder (made changes in localhost and etc). How do I push the changes to the server? I was using GitShell commands on my branch, with a git add, commit, and push.

Answer (score 0):

You push local changes to a remote repo with the `push` command:

```
git push origin <branch>
```

You can read more about how to `push`, along with other Git tools and workflows, from the [**FREE online Pro Git book**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Pushing-to-Your-Remotes).